# Lazy<'T> vs anonymous functions

Tags: f#, lazy-evaluation

Is there any advantage to using the .NET lazy operator instead of a plain function?

For example:

```
let x = lazy ...
let y = lazy (1 + x.Value)

let x = (fun () -> ...)
let y = (fun () -> 1 + x())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between a lazy value and a function is that a lazy value is evaluated only once. It then caches the result and accessing it again will not recalculate the value. A function is evaluated each time you call it.

This has performance implications and it also matters when you have side effects. For example, the following prints `"calculating x"` just once:

```
let x = lazy (printfn "calculating x"; 1)
let y = lazy (1 + x.Value)
y.Value + y.Value
```

The following prints `"calculating x"` two times:

```
let x = (fun () -> printfn "calculating x"; 1)
let y = (fun () -> 1 + x())
y () + y ()
```

Comment: Assuming that all calls are needed only once, would lazy hurt performance?

Comment: @alakfq I don't think it would hurt in any notable way, but it's always to measure such things if performance really matters to you!